# Filtering specific lines in csv keeping track of last value

Tags: python, csv

I've got a .csv file with different data formats and I'm trying to operate with the values on the same column.

my csv file is something like this:

```
"int","float","stirng", more data
```

Example:

```
"2","1.378","Johnny"
"1","1.379","Walker"
"5","1.380","Jack"
"8","1.700","Daniels"
"8","1.710","Baileys"
"8","1.381","Monkey"
"8","1.711","Shoulder"
"8","1.383","Captain"
"8","1.385","Morgan"
"8","1.392","Drinks"
More rows
```

I would like to subtract values in the second column if their difference is >x.
 (only those, I don't care about the others).

My code so far:

```
with open ('input.csv', 'r') as file, open ('output.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    readCSV = csv.reader(file)
    writeCSV = csv.writer(f_out, lineterminator='\n')
    last = None

    for row in readCSV:
        datalat = float(row[1])

        if last is not None:
            #print("difference -> %f" %(datalat-last))
            outp = (datalat-last)
            if outp <= 0.02:
                writeCSV.writerow(row)
            last = datalat
```

The output looks like:

```
5,1.380,Jack
8,1.710,Baileys
8,1.381,Monkey
8,1.383,Captain
8,1.385,Morgan
8,1.392,Drinks
```

But I would like it to be:

```
"2","1.378","Johnny"
"1","1.379","Walker"
"5","1.380","Jack"
"8","1.381","Monkey"
"8","1.383","Captain"
"8","1.385","Morgan"
"8","1.392","Drinks"
```

So what it should do is only write rows that have less than 0.02 difference, IF there is a row with a bigger difference discard it, then compare the next row to the last written row, as opposed to the last discarded row.

Comment: You're not updating `last` anywhere

Comment: @MosesKoledoye sorry, I missed a line while copying my code. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You should take the absolute value (using `abs`) of the difference as you don't know apriori which of the two is greater.
2. Only update `last` if the condition is fulfilled, so `last` is never a discarded value.

---

```
last = float(next(readCSV)[1])  # assign first reference value
f_out.seek(0)                   # return to start of file
for row in readCSV:
    datalat = float(row[1])
    diff = abs(datalat-last)
    if diff <= 0.02:
        writeCSV.writerow(row)
        last = datalat
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for your input!